# Displaying JSON data in drop-down in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-options

my document.json file contains data like

```
[
    {"name" :"B"},
    {"name" :"A"},
    {"name" :"D"},
    {"name" :"E"}
]
```

when i try to display the json data in drop-down list, the last element `E` only displayed in drop down .my html file like

```
<select ng-model="selectedTestAccount" ng-options="c as c.name for c in testAccounts"></select>
```

and my script file like

```
sampleApp.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.selectedTestAccount = null;
  $scope.testAccounts = [];

  $http.get('document.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.testAccounts = data;
  });
});
```

How can i display this document.json data in drop-down list with default selected as first element in AngularJS. Any guidelines please

Comment: I think your data is not correct. Because you have same names of each key so it is getting overwritten by other one. So in last there is one key with just value E.

Comment: Thank you ,just now i edited the JSON object structure ,but the name is common for my requirement .

Comment: No I am not saying to remove name field. But before that you had 4 name fields in one object. which is not possible.

Comment: yah ,i edited the JSON structure ,thank you

Comment: I think the comments which helped you are seems important for your question. You should vote them, so they  will appear in starting of the post and will be helpful for other viewers. Thanx

Comment: you have fixed problem in question itself. You should not be doing like this, because other viewers won't get what was the problem.

Comment: Actually I didn't check the code and execute the code after editing the json data structure and i am facing the default display of first element in drop down list ,after @Jerrad demo i got what are necessary steps to display the data, Thank you  for your suggestions .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON isn't quite right.  You need to have braces around each item, like this:

```
[ 
  { "name" :"B" }, 
  { "name" :"A" }, 
  { "name" :"D" }, 
  { "name" :"E" } 
]
```

You can select the first item in the dropdown by default like this:

```
$scope.selectedTestAccount = $scope.testAccounts[0];
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/URgRU52sslPvSHutCmpt?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you ,just now i got my json object structure, but your answer  not reading the documet.json  file ,which is important for me .can you answer reading the document.json file .

Comment: @Shekkar, I've updated the demo in my answer to read from the document.json file.

Comment: Thank you @Jerrad ,i got where i stopped your Demo helps me every thing